# Attaching custom escape sequence to kHome key

Tags: terminal, escape-characters

My idea is to attach an action in vim to kHome key (Home located on numeric keypad) that will not affect ordinary Home key.
In terminal I run:

```
$ cat
# pressed kHome
^[[1~
# pressed Home
^[[1~
```

So, these keys give the same escape sequence. I decided to attach my own escape sequence to kHome.

```
$ showkey
# pressed kHome
keycode 71 press
keycode 71 release 
# pressed Home
keycode 102 press
keycode 102 release
```

So, kHomes code is 71. I created a file ~/funcskeys:

```
keycode 71 = F13
string F13 = "\033[1;5G"
```

I don't fully understand how custom escape sequences should be constructed, so I created it using an old answer and examples from the Internet.
Then I ran as root:

```
# loadkeys -c ./funcskeys
```

When I run `cat` again I still get the old escase sequence:

```
$ cat
# pressed kHome
^[[1~
```

What's wrong? Maybe, I need to delete the old escape sequence from the key first?